# Symfony 2 SonataAdminBundle broken styles

Tags: css, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

After I have installed SonataAdminBundle 2.4.*@dev style of buttons for `sonata_type_model_list` has been broken (There is no borders and you hover to the link everything blanks out). Also style for choice field has been broken.

---

`sonata_type_model_list`

[image: sonata_type_model_list]

---

choice field

[image: choice field]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What was the version before?

Comment: May be you installed assets as hard copy? Try to `php app/console assets:install --symlink`

Comment: All assets installed as symlink

Comment: Did you run this command after update?

Comment: Of course I have to run this command after update